# Capturing element position in a file with an xml reader. Offset issue

Tags: .net, xml

I'm trying to capture elements positions in an xml file (to build an index).
But I've encountered some offset issues, linePosition is shifted to the right (sometimes by 2, sometimes by three).

Here is a sample code and a .netfiddle to present the problem

https://dotnetfiddle.net/8byHGW

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace IXmlLineInfoTests
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string Xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><snapshot><offrdefs><offrdef></offrdef></offrdefs><offers><offer></offer></offers></snapshot>";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(Xml))
            {
                using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
                {
                    IXmlLineInfo xli = (IXmlLineInfo)xr;
                    var startLinePosition = 0;
                    startLinePosition = xli.LinePosition;
                    Console.WriteLine($"before reading: {startLinePosition}");
                    while (xr.Read())
                    {
                        startLinePosition = xli.LinePosition;
                        if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"declaration: {startLinePosition}");
                        }
                        else if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                        {

                            if (xr.Name == "offer")
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"offer: {startLinePosition}");
                            }
                            else if (xr.Name == "snapshot")
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"snapshot: {startLinePosition}");
                            }
                            else if (xr.Name == "offrdefs")
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"offrdefs: {startLinePosition}");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output is

```
before reading: 0
declaration: 3
snapshot: 41
offrdefs: 51
offer: 99
```

And I've expected to have this

```
before reading: 0
declaration: 0
snapshot: 39
offrdefs: 50
offer: 98
```

What am I doing wrong ? Or is it normal ?

Comment: IMHO, the entire approach is very questionable. XML is not a string. An XML element position could be expressed by using XPath.

Comment: Thanks for you input.
I'm doing this because my end goal is to take pieces of those xml files to copy/modify them later multiple times and in a repeated manner over time (this is why I'm trying to build an index of element positions). 
Those are huge and numerous xml files where xpath request is no match in term of performance with a Stream.seek at the correct position.